# Write a function in Eigen that returns a sparsematrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

Can anyone give me a tip on writing a function in c++ that returns a sparse matrix in eigen?

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

SparseMatrix f(){return SparseMatrix<double> M(10,10);}

int main()
{
SparseMatrix M(10,10);
M = f();
}
```

Comment: Did you read the tutorial at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html?

Comment: Yes looked through it, but I did not see anything that helped me for this specific question. From what I gathered what I posted in the question should work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is all that needs to be done:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
typedef SparseMatrix<double> SparseDouble; 
SparseDouble f(){return SparseMatrix<double> M(10,10);}

int main()
{
SparseMatrix<double> M(10,10) = f();
}
```